# Associating HasOne relationship without saving it in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, model-associations, has-one

I have created a custom push() method which saves all model's relations in cascading manner and collects full snapshot of entity and children details for audit log.

Everything works fine with belongsTo and hasMany relations. I just do as follows:

```
    $ae->target()->associate(new AuditableEntryTarget(["name" => "single target"]));

    $ae->children->add(new AuditableEntryChild(["name" => "one of children"]));
    $ae->children->add(new AuditableEntryChild(["name" => "two of children"]));

    // add grandchildren to the first child
    $ae->children[0]->children->add(new AuditableEntrySubChild(["name" => "one of subchildren for first child"]));

    // add target subchild
    $ae->target->subtarget()->associate(new AuditableEntryTargetChild(["name" => "single target child"]));      

    // my custom method which saves and collects to audit log all the children, no matter if they are attached through hasMany or belongsTo
    $ae->push();
```

But the problem is with hasOne relation. It does not offer any way to attach the related model to my root model without saving it first. HasOne relation has only save() method in Laravel:

```
 /**
 * Attach a model instance to the parent model.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function save(Model $model)
{
    $model->setAttribute($this->getPlainForeignKey(), $this->getParentKey());

    return $model->save() ? $model : false;
}
```

which, as you see, not only associates, but also saves the model. To be able to detect all changes for fields, my method requires that the relations are attached to the model but not saved yet because else I won't be able to intercept the save process and attach the data to my snapshot. `BelongsTo` has `associate` and `hasMany` has `add` for attaching models without saving them yet, but I cannot find anything similar for hasOne.

**Is there any way to attach a new model instance to hasOne relation without causing it to be saved immediately (something like `associate` for `belongsTo` or `add` for `hasMany`)?**

Answer (score 4):

With help of Laracasts guys, the workaround seems to be

```
$model->setRelation('child', $childInstance);
```

Still, it's strange that Laravel does not initialize hasOne relationship the same way as it inits hasMany.